# Running a RESTful Web Service in Eclipse with Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, tomcat, servlets

I was developing a RESTful Web Service's example using Apache Tomcat in Eclipse, but I don't accomplish this example works.

First,I configured **Apache Tomcat** on **8080 port**, so when I run the server I can see the welcoming screen.

I created a project called "**RestEjemplo**", then I created **"Hola.java"** class which is in **"es.rest.test"** package

Below I show the code of **Hola.java**

```
package es.rest.test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


// POJO, no interface no extends

// Sets the path to base URL + /hola
@Path("/hola")
public class Hola {

    // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hola Jersey";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello(){
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hola> Hola Jersey" + "</hola>";
    }

    // This method is called if HTML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello(){
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hola Jersey" + "</title>" +
                "<body><h1>" + "Hola Jersey" + "</h1></body>" +
                "</html>";
    }

}
```

And it is my **web.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RestEjemplo</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>es.rest.test</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

After that, I checked that param-value was the same name of my project's package, and the others parameters

I click over my class **Helo.java** and *"Run as > Run on Server"* and Eclipse launch the following direction automatically

```
http://localhost:8080/RestEjemplo/WEB-INF/classes/es/rest/test/Hola.java
```

which, I think that it is wrong. In any case, the web browser has an error.

```
Estado HTTP 404 -
type: Informe de estado
mensaje:
descripción: El recurso requerido no está disponible

Apache Tomcat/7.0.63
```

In addition, if I change de URI/URL to another that has more sense, like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/RestEjemplo/rest/hola
```

Eclipse show me the same error. **I don't know how to solve this** because I think that Apache's configuration is OK, and the last URI used is also OK.
**What is it that I'm wrong?**

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost:8080/rest/hola

Comment: Yes, but doesn't work

Comment: The param-value in the web.xml should contain the java package name and not the project name. <param-value>es.rest.test</param-value>

Comment: Sorry, I changed the param-value to "es.rest.test"  but doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting HTTP 404 every time you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Secondly, the url-pattern in your servlet mapping should be as follows:   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>. And the access URL should be http://localhost:8080/RestEjemplo/hola

Comment: @Drona I have changed the url-pattern but doesn't work. Eclipse shows me the same HTTP 404 message

Comment: Yes @morsor , when Eclipse shows me the HTTP 404 message, I refer it like "doesn't work" because I should to see "Hola Jersey"

Comment: I see all kinds of references to tutorials on other stackoverflow questions; at any point during the development of this test code, was the official jersey documentation referenced at all? https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html and more specifically: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.3

Answer (score 0):

Jersey 2.0 does not recognize `init-param` with name `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages`

Try to change it to

```
jersey.config.server.provider.packages
```

Then instead of :

```
http://localhost:8080/RestEjemplo/rest/hola
```

You can use something like this

```
 http://localhost:8080/es.rest.test/rest/hola
```

You may also want to look at this resourse
[Jersey REST Web Service, Tomcat, Eclipse and 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709039/jersey-rest-web-service-tomcat-eclipse-and-404s?rq=1)

Comment: I get HTTP 404, again

Comment: It seems you're using Jersey 2.0. check once with the updated answer.

Comment: I am using Jersey 2.19 and I change _com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages_ to _jersey.config.server.provider.packages_ and doesn't work. Also I was reading the thread you recommend me, and then I copy the code to a new project on Eclipse but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If your URL param is ,

```
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
```

hit,

http://localhost:8080/RestEjemplo/rest/hola/ok

Try This:
Change your method and hit above url:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/ok")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hola Jersey";
    }
```

Comment: I hit http://localhost:8080/RestEjemplo/rest/hola previously, but doesn't work yet

Comment: are you hitting this url in eclipse? @JoséMaríaValbae

Comment: Yes, I am hitting the url in the web browser who belong to Eclipse, and also in Chrome, but neither works

Comment: I have changed the code like you have written before, and Eclipse shows me the same message HTTP 404...

Comment: i would recommend you to try and run this example http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/

Comment: but in that example he develops a maven project. In any case Eclipse doesn't work